# Create progressbar with minimum step of two and maximum five

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple list.

```
  const [progressBar, setProgressBar] = useState([
    { isActive: false, name: "step1" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step2" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step3" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step4" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step5" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step6" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step7" },
  ]);
```

I show this list user and user able to change it.But the problem is that need to create condition when user choose minimum 2 and maximum  5 gap.

For example when page load the radio button is not picked.User can't just pick first item he need to pick second. Or if he picked second after when he want to change he can only change maximum from 2 to 7 (minimum from 2 to 4). Something like that I think I can explain logic.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-meadow-bz4bs?file=/src/App.js)

```
const [progressBar, setProgressBar] = useState([
    { isActive: false, name: "step1" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step2" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step3" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step4" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step5" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step6" },
    { isActive: false, name: "step7" }
  ]);

  const checkMinimumOfTwoAndMaxOfFive = (
    index,
    idx,
    returnIsActive,
    returnNonActive
  ) => {
    if (index >= idx) {
      return returnIsActive;
    } else {
      return returnNonActive;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {progressBar.map((el, i) => (
        <span
          key={el.name}
          className={el.isActive ? "red" : ""}
          onClick={() =>
            setProgressBar(
              progressBar.map((item, idx) =>
                checkMinimumOfTwoAndMaxOfFive(
                  i,
                  idx,
                  { ...item, isActive: true },
                  { ...item, isActive: false }
                )
              )
            )
          }
        >
          {el.name}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

**First try:**

I try find last `isActive` element and manipulate it.

```
const gap = array
  .slice()
  .reverse()
  .findIndex((item) => item.isActive);


if (gap >= 4 || gap === 0 || gap === -1) {
  return returnNonActive;
} else {
  if (index >= idx) {
    return returnIsActive;
  } else {
    return returnNonActive;
  }
}
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

Working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-vaughan-cc2r8?file=/src/App.js:92-917

```
  const limit = 5;
  const size = 7;
  const minimum = 2;
  const [step, setStep] = useState(minimum - 1);

  const stepUp = () => {
    if (step < limit) {
      setStep(step + 1);
    }
  };

  const stepDown = () => {
    if (step >= minimum) {
      setStep(step - 1);
    }
  };

  const Steps = ({ step }) => {
    const Components = [];
    for (let index = 0; index <= size; index++) {
      Components.push(<Step name={`step${index}`} isActive={index <= step} />);
    }

    return Components;
  };

  const Step = ({ name, isActive }) => (
    <span className={isActive ? "red" : ""} onClick={stepUp}>
      {name}
    </span>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Steps step={step} />
      <div>
        <button onClick={stepUp}>STEP UP</button>
        <button onClick={stepDown}>STEP DOWN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank's for answer. But your code not working correctly. I can pick  minimum step one. But minimum need to be two. Also when I clicked to step 7 it pick from step0 to step1. It need to be picked from step0 to step5

Comment: I added the variables at the top so you can change them accordingly

Comment: Yes you do. But this is not work as expected. As I said I can still pick step by one. But need to be minimum 2. But this minimum which you added working only in the beginning.

Comment: Ok, what you need is something that limits the steps to 5 and has the minimum steps of 2?
or do you need to add 2 steps a time minimum?

Comment: i made some changes to the code, try it now, see if it fits

Comment: Yes exactly. And where's your new code which you changed?

Comment: I did not see any changes. Works as the previous code.

Comment: i asked you between two options above, tell me which one you are trying to achieve, you answered yes but that doesn't tell me nothing

Comment: I answered your question. I need to step between two numbers. For example. From 0 to 2. From 2 to 4. From 4 to 6. And vice verse. User can't go from 4 to 5 or from 5 to 6 this is one step which is not acceptable.Second maximum step is need to be 5. From 0 to 5 from 1 to 6. He can't jump from 1 to 7 or 8 or 9. Only 5 step. But he can choose from 1 to 4 or 5.Because maximum is 5.